# Powershell intermittently able to set / unset a file as Read-Only

Tags: windows, powershell

Writing a short script to make all files in a directory either Read-Only or not.

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [bool]$isReadOnly,
    [string]$source_path  = 'C:\Reports\'
)
    Get-ChildItem $source_path | ForEach-Object {
        $_.IsReadOnly = $isReadOnly
        # I've also tried this, which does the same thing:
        # Set-ItemProperty -Path $_.FullName -Name IsReadOnly -Value $isReadOnly -Force
        Write-Output ('Read Only? ' + $_.IsReadOnly)
    }
```

The Output looks like this (with three files in the directory):

```
Supply values for the following parameters:
isReadOnly: $false
Read Only? True
Read Only? True
Read Only? True
```

I'm logged in as Admin. Seems like sometimes the script works, other times it doesn't. What would be keeping this from working?

Comment: If file is being used by another application.

Comment: Try setting the attributes directly `$_.Attributes = $_.Attributes -bor [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly`. But depending the files & locations the system may not allow to set read-only for whatever reasons. Maybe a parent folder is set as read-only and files automatically inherit the flag.

Comment: @jdweng I don't think the files are being used since I can manually change the properties, as well as delete the files.

Comment: Does this happen on your local machine, or on a network location? And how are you determining that the read only attribute isn’t set? I’ve seen glitches in the past with exotic network file systems with supposedly 100% compatible SMB interfaces doing weird things and sometimes needing a refresh in Windows Explorer to pick up new files or attribute changes, for example because file system watching doesn’t work properly…

Comment: `[bool]'$false' -eq $true`. If you're gonna accept string input for `-isReadOnly`, you need to call `[bool]::Parse()` or similar to actually parse the value

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think a couple of things were happening.

The final code looks like this:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [bool]$isReadOnly,
    [string]$source_path  = 'C:\Reports\'
)

# Change the setting
    Get-ChildItem $source_path | ForEach-Object {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $_.FullName -Name IsReadOnly -Value $isReadOnly -Force
        Write-Output ('ran with: ' + $isReadOnly)
    }

# Check the setting
    Get-ChildItem $source_path | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Output ('Read Only? ' + $_.IsReadOnly)
    }
```

1. As @mclayton suggested, the IsReadOnly property wasn't refreshing in the same loop. Moving this to a separate loop (Check the setting) lets you visualize the change after running the script.
2. Didn't see @Mathias R. Jessen's response until I posted this, but the bigger issue was typings. Basically how the boolean value is passed in changes its type.

Passing in the parameter after the command works as expected:

```
    PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> & '.\setReportReadOnlyProperty.ps1' $true

    ran with: True
    ran with: True
    ran with: True
    Read Only? True
    Read Only? True
    Read Only? True
```

But passing in the parameter when prompted seems to read wrong

```
    PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> & '.\setReportReadOnlyProperty.ps1'

    cmdlet setReportReadOnlyProperty.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
    Supply values for the following parameters:
    isReadOnly: $false
    ran with: True
    ran with: True
    ran with: True
    Read Only? True
    Read Only? True
    Read Only? True
```

Basically, typing anything reads as $true:

```
    PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> & '.\setReportReadOnlyProperty.ps1'

    cmdlet setReportReadOnlyProperty.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
    Supply values for the following parameters:
    isReadOnly: asdfasdfa
    ran with: True
    ran with: True
    ran with: True
    Read Only? True
    Read Only? True
    Read Only? True
```

So since everything was reading as $true, the script was working but would only make the files Read-Only.

Comment: "So since everything was reading as $true" - did you try just pressing [Enter]? :) An empty string will evaluate to `$false`